# How to get String Value as Input and Populate ListView using Query in Android

Tags: string, sqlite, listview, android-edittext

I am new at Android so i really don't know How to get String Value from `EditText` on Button Click(Search), which must populate a `ListView` using raw Query in `SqlLite` Database. I have One `Activity` Which consist of `EditText` and Search`Button` while another `Activity` which consist of `ListView`. Which means the `Results` should  display on another `Activity` (in ListView). . Thanks in Advance to All.

Answer (score 0):

@Uzair try breaking your question into sub parts. Its a lot of code that needs to be explained. So try breaking your queries.